# $index is not working inside of ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following ng-repeat HTML code:

```
<group ng-repeat="group in groups" groups="groups" group="group"></group>
```

Which works great for me at generating the groups from my object. The problem I am having is that $index though doesn't work inside of this directive.

So in the Group Template:

```
<div>
{{$index}} - {{group.Name}} {{group.Target}}
</div>
```

The $index is always undefined.

Here is the directive:

```
app.directive('group', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            groups: '=',
            group: '='
        },
        templateUrl: '../../Content/templates/RecruitingGroups/Group.html',
        link: function (scope, el) {
            //Set Rules
            if (scope.group.Rule) {
                scope.ruleRules = scope.group.Rule.Rules;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Try `$parent.$index` as your directive creates an isolated scope.

Comment: Or pass the $index to the directive if you do not want to get tied up in the parent-child-relationship.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your directive uses an isolate scope. To access `$index` inside the parent scope you need to use `$parent`:

```
<div>
    {{$parent.$index}} - {{group.Name}} {{group.Target}}
</div>
```

<kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/4782/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$index` you can define current key in your ng-repeat

```
<group ng-repeat="(key, group) in groups" groups="groups" group="group"></group>

<div>
  {{key}} - {{group.Name}} {{group.Target}}
</div>
```

Here this key will do the same thing as **$index**
**$index** will refer to our parent DOM but key will refer to ng-repeat parameter only
So sometime to access $index in parent scope you have to use **$parent.$index** and instead of $index you can use **key** also